# Weight capacity - TV Stand

Tags: weight-capacity

[image]Trying to get a better sense of how much weight this old TV stand can hold. I'm considering putting a 75 gallon aquarium on top which can push 850+ lbs once full.

By the look of this, do you think I should be confident that this piece can handle the weight?

Thanks for the help!
[image]

Comment: It's a coffee table I think...back from the days when TVs were in console cabinets. What does the bottom look like? Can you add a picture of the bottom? Are there "feet" to support the weight in the corners _and_ the center? Or are the corners the only points that support weight?

Comment: Yes very much what @gnicko said, it's important that this has some support in the centre. Don't worry if there's nothing currently, it'll be quite easy to add something, but without it I wouldn't trust this much weight to the unit even with it being so well distributed over the top. Once there is central support the unit looks fairly robust and I think it should take the weight fine.

Comment: One additional point, are water splashes a regular occurrence around aquariums? If so you might want to consider doing something with the finish on the top prior to use, if aesthetics are important. The current finish is aged and not in good shape (and might not have been sufficient when new anyway) and you're likely to get further stains if you do nothing. The whole unit doesn't have to be refinished, you can refresh or refinish the top only as the surface most likely to encounter the water.

Comment: I promise you , water will ruin the finish of the table. Vertical dead weight is not the problem ; The possible problem is any force from the side.

Comment: @blacksmith37, the finish is *already* ruined ^_^ Re. racking, I'd say this unit (in contrast to many we've answered similar Qs on) is actually quite resistant to it because of the positioning of the central cabinet with the outlying corner supports (which don't look wimpy). Of course a proper call on this is really better made with the thing in front of us so we can look at everything that might be relevant, although sadly that still might not allow more than complete guesswork at the joinery.

Answer (score 4):

Without on-site testing, it might be a challenge to make a guess.

How do you feel about the floor being able to manage the weight?

Measure the width and length to get square meters or square feet and determine pounds per square foot or kilos per square meter. You could then test the weakest segment of the table, the ends/leafs with an appropriate lower weight that matches your calculations.

For example, I'll guess at 18" x 48", or 1.5' x 4' or 6 square feet. 850 pounds divided by six is 141 and two thirds pounds per square foot.

I'm more than 141 pounds by an unfortunate amount and I would feel reasonably comfortable standing on the open-air segment of the table. My feet would cover slightly less than one square foot which means the numbers get higher than your test value.